# Function is not changing the value of pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I think the code is self-explanatory:

```
MyClass* pointer = NULL;
changePointer( pointer );
if (pointer == NULL) 
{
   // it's entering here :(
}



    void changePointer( MyClass* p)
    {
        MyClass* temp = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < myContainer.size(); ++i) 
        {
            p = &(myContainer[i]);

            if (p == NULL) 
            {
                 // it's not entering here :)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value when you don't use references. Pointers are not references.

Comment: @chris Pointers are not passed by reference (by default) to be exact.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, Yeah, I guess. I meant what I said, but that was silly.

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to change the value of pointers you don't own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer is being passed by value, not by reference, so the original variable cannot be changed. You need to change the function signature to:

```
void changePointer(MyClass** p)
```

...and pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
changePointer(&pointer);
```

You'll need to make some corresponding changes in the body of the function, too.

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass the pointer by reference, if you want to change what the pointer points to in the caller function

```
void changePointer(MyClass*& p)
```

**You dont need to change** how you **call** the function, or how you **use** `p` in the function. Now if you change the target of `p` inside the function, it will be **changed in the original variable** as well.

Is this what you are asking?